# File types recognized in the GUI, but not on command line

Tags: debian, file-types

I recently realized that `file` on Debian Bullseye won't recognize some of the file formats I'm dealing with, telling me they are just ZIP files:

```
user@host:~ $ file file.docx   # Correct, not a regular ZIP file
file.docx: Microsoft Word 2007+

user@host:~ $ file file.key    # Incorrect, also not a regular ZIP file
file.key: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract
```

However, if I look at the files with `pcmanfm`, I see the file types are recognized correctly:

```
"file.docx" (50.5kB) Word 2007 document
"file.key" (10.4MB) Apple Keynote 5 presentation
```

Is it possible to tell `file` to use the same magic file than `pcmanfm` uses, or somehow update the default `/etc/magic` to make `file` aware of popular document formats?

Comment: For the .docx files at least, they ARE zip files, and they contain among others, XML files. Indeed, this is the same with LibreOffice/OpenOffice files.

Comment: @Bib .key files are also zip files (at least since 2020, see [here](http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/IWork)), so `file` is not "wrong".

Comment: I've noticed PCMan incorrectly typed GnuPG keygrip files in `~/gnupg/private-keys-v1.d` as "Apple Keynote 5 presentation" files, so it's file-type magic is a little loosey-goosey.

Comment: @terdon That's exactly my point: `file` correctly reports `docx` as a Word document, despite it also being a Zip file (and a binary data file, for that matter). Keynote files are Zip files as well, but that's not what I want to see. I tried to clarify this in the question.

Comment: @frabjous Here's an implementation of `file` that is always "not wrong": `echo "$1: data"` :)

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev You are correct. Not being specific can make information worthless without its being wrong. I wasn't criticizing the question – it's a good question – I was just following up on Bib's comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PCManFM doesn’t use the same kind of magic file as `file` does, it uses [shared-mime-info](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/shared-mime-info/). That knows about [Apple Keynote 5 files](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xdg/shared-mime-info/-/blob/62baee5169438bdf86c5d022c72796177b878c57/data/freedesktop.org.xml.in#L7580); it identifies them by their “PK” marker (common for all ZIP files), the presence of an `index.apxl` file inside that ZIP file, and their `.key` extensions.

`file`’s current magic library [doesn’t know about Apple Keynote 5 files](https://github.com/file/file/blob/master/magic/Magdir/apple) (it does know about [Microsoft Office XML files](https://github.com/file/file/blob/master/magic/Magdir/msooxml)).

To teach `file` about Keynote files, you can add your own magic entry using the information in the shared MIME database; alternatively, you can use `mimetype`, which uses that information to extract a file’s MIME type.

I think the best option is to [file a bug](https://bugs.astron.com) asking for Keynote recognition in `file`.

Comment: Thanks, the output of `mimetype --file-compat file.key` matches the `pcmanfm` tooltips perfectly!